# data is undefined in toast - ReactJS, Nodejs, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, toast

```
      http
        .post("/user/createAccount", data)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          navigate("/user/login");
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          toast.error(`${err.response.data.message}`);
        });
```

```
  let user = await UserAccount.findOne({
    where: { emailAccount: data.emailAccount },
    where: { phoneNo: data.phoneNo },
  });
  if (user) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Email or Phone Number already exists." });
    return;
  }
```

The error message is not showing on using toast and data is undefined.

I deleted the `.data.message` and the toast pop up works again, however when `.data.message` is added back, data is undefined

Comment: does your api return `{ data: { message: 'error' } }` on error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error!
It seems the code below seems to turn the data into undefined.

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location="/user/login"
  }
})
```